# Git clone of OpenShift repository hangs in linux, but not windows

Tags: linux, git, clone, openshift

Lately I have been unable to clone my openshift application repositories using git in linux.

I have the following three OS installations:

- Ubuntu 13.10: Git 1.9.1
- Ubuntu 14.04: Git 1.9.1
- Windows 7: Git 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0

Git is working on all three for any repository other than those hosted by OpenShift. However, only the Windows 7 git works with OpenShift; both Ubuntu installations hang on git clone operations for any OpenShift repository.

The RHC git-clone has also been tested, but since this relies on the local git installation, it too hangs on ubuntu as expected.

By 'hangs' I am referring to git becoming non-responsive at any point during the git-clone operation, usually at one of the three following places:

- "Cloning into ''"
- "remote: Compressing objects: X% ..."
- "Receiving objects: X% ..."

Authentication has been tested, and is certainly not the cause. All other RHC operations seem to work properly for all OS installations.

---

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I am not such a Windows fan ;)

Comment: Did you try to export GIT_TRACE=1 and GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 in the shell, before cloning the repository? This logs some debug messages. Maybe that helps to narrow down the problem!?

Comment: GIT_TRACE and GIT_TRACE_PACKET did not help unfortunately, but I have discovered some additional info: git clone seems to work at my university, using their wireless network. I recently installed a new modem so it may be that the ssh protocol is somehow blocked for ubuntu but not windows. By assumption, the 'git clone' trials which worked in ubuntu may have been using https instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create your app with the following flag

rhc app-create --no-git --no-dns

This will create the app without waiting for DNS name resolution on  your local machine and no git clone at the end.

The results will then give you a git URL to use. Try doing a git clone using that url and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had tested the git url of existing apps and none worked. Recently I replaced my modem and the issue was immediately resolved. I am still unsure of the exact cause but will be in conversation with my ISP until it is determined.